# Algorithms in C++ by Robert Sedgewick experiences

Tags: c++

How good is this book for learning algorithm creation, based on experiences ?

Comment: depends on your current level of knowledge, but yes it is a good book.

Comment: I would also suggest searching SO, are there are many related questions...

Comment: I'm a beginner in C++ prog., what is your suggestion of; when should I start learning algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a good book but this does not mean it is good for you - maybe you find it at google books so you can have a look in it.

Comment: @learningtolive Have you tried Cormen's *"Introduction to Algorithms?"*

Comment: Well I'm a beginner in C++ programming, basically I just want to know for the future...

Comment: Well, it slightly depends on what you want to do with your knowledge. Learning algorithm is good, but learning the most helpful for you is better.

Answer (score 3):

The most common algorithms book I have seen is [Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein's Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844), which you may see written elsewhere as CLRS or "The MIT Algorithms Text". It's not quite as pervasive as the Dragon Book is for compiler design, but it's close.

Strictly speaking, when talking about algorithms, the programming language you decide to use rarely makes much of a difference. Algorithms are about speeding up the machine's way of thinking of general problems, not a particular way of processing a particular input with a particular implementation.

Comment: @learningtolive: That question doesn't make any sense. That's entirely dependent on how often you program, how well you know a language, how useful algorithms will be for your particular application, how well you "get" algorithms.... there's no way for anyone to reasonably answer that.

Comment: As I said. I'm just a beginner. :)

Comment: @Billy: It makes a difference if your language is purely functional or not :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: It makes a difference when you go to implement things, but you can implemenent Binary Search or Depth First Search or Breadth First Search or Boyer Moore or ..... it does not matter.

Comment: How does a purely functional bubble sort look like? Also quick sort cannot *really* be done in purely functional languages, because one of quick sort's biggest advantages over other many other sorting algorithms is that it can sort in situ, which by definition is impossible in purely functional languages.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Yes,  some algorithms would be different or impossible to implement using functional languages, but the study of algorithms themselves does not change.